# Access to web.config connectionstrings from console app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, console, web-config

I have searched for other postings asking this same question.  The typical answer is "use app.config instead".

All of the responses saying "use app.config instead" are *useless*.  I do not want to read from app.config, I want read from web.config.  If I wanted to read from app.config I would not have to be asking this question.

If you want to have a reason, I need a console app in order to be able to be scheduled for automatic execution.  It must, however, share the same configuration as the web application that is installed on this machine.  So stop trying to avoid the issue by saying "use app.config instead" and answer the question -- or come right out and say it is not possible.

Please, is there a way to access **web.config** (not app.config) from a console app?

I am currently using c# in visual studio 2008

Answer (score 1):

Web.config is just an xml file. You can read anything form it using XmlDocument class.  Load web.config into it and then use XPath query to find your connection strings.